# Is it possible to identify the wands in the Wizarding World logo?

Tags: harry-potter, object-identification, pottermore

The Official Wizarding World logo depicts several wands:

[image: Wizarding World logo]
 <sub>*click to enlarge*</sub>

The middle wand seems to be the Elder Wand. Is it possible to identify the other wands (as in who are their owners)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Wizarding World themselves have answered this in the announcement of the new logo.

> The new Wizarding World logo is an open book, reflecting its literary origins, and contains elements emblematic of the beloved characters from both Harry Potter and Fantastic Beasts. Astute fans will instantly notice the iconic lightning bolt, as well as a subtle nod to magical creatures, embedded in the logo. Additionally, the book’s fanned-open ‘pages’ are actually wands, each belonging to one of the legendary wizards or witches from the two franchises.
>
> The order of the wands is also symbolic: reflecting the evolution of the films, they begin with those chosen for the Harry Potter characters, followed by key characters from Fantastic Beasts. **From left to right, they are the wands belonging to Voldemort, Ron Weasley, Hermione Granger, Harry Potter, Albus Dumbledore (the Elder Wand), Newt Scamander, Tina Goldstein, Queenie Goldstein, and Gellert Grindelwald (the wand he possessed before claiming the Elder Wand).**
>
> All of the wands point inward, inviting both devoted and new fans, as well as future generations, to discover more of the magic and adventure of the Wizarding World.
>
> <sub>[Wizarding World, New logo marks an exciting year ahead for the Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/news/wizarding-world-brand-logo-launch)</sub>

Note that the bottom horizontal lines that make up the cover of the book and join at the spine aren’t wands but just that, lines to show the cover.

Not to take the fun out of it completely, here's a comparison of all the wands:

- Voldemort (first image rotated)

  [image: Close up of Voldemort's wand from the logo] [image: Voldemort's wand: slim carved bone with a larger bone handle]
- Ron Weasley, specifically this would be his second wand

  [image: Close up of Ron's wand from the logo] [image: Ron's wand: dimpled wood with a knotted end]
- Hermione Granger

  [image: Close up of Hermione's wand from the logo] [image: Hermione's wand: wooden with vine like carvings on it]
- Harry Potter

  [image: Close up of Harry's wand from the logo] [image: Harry's wand: carved wood with an untouched bark handle]
- Albus Dumbledore (the Elder Wand)

  [image: Close up of the Elder Wand from the logo] [image: Elder Wand: wooden with larger bulges along its length]
- Newt Scamander

  [image: Close up of Newt's wand from the logo] [image: Newt's wand: simple and plain straight with two tones of wood]
- Tina Goldstein

  [image: Close up of Tina's wand from the logo] [image: Tina's wand: Dark wood, plain with a simple handle]
- Queenie Goldstein

  [image: Close up of Queenie's wand from the logo] [image: Queenie's wand: black with a shell carved pearl handle]
- Gellert Grindelwald (the wand he possessed before claiming the Elder Wand)  (first image rotated)

  [image: Close up of Grindelwald's wand from the logo] [image: Grindelwald's wand: black and twisting with thorns poking out of it]

Comment: so I guess the "Wizarding World" is inimitably tied to the WB films, not merely the Rowling Potterverse textually. As servicably decent as the films they are, I would hope that someday we'd get a more robust Netflix type series that does the text full justice

Comment: @NKCampbell: I'm rather doubtful of that. The films made an insane amount of money, regardless of how fans may feel about them, and it would be difficult to compete with them after the fact. But I could imagine them doing something safer, like *Law & Order: Magical Britain* (but with a snappier title, such as *Aurors*).

Comment: I suppose it is too much to hope that JKR would actually *write novels* rather than just fob off screenplays.